# getrlimit() returns wrong value?

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, system-calls

Can someone explain to me why the following program creates 7185 threads instead of 7455?

```c
void *thr_crt(void *arg)
{
    sleep(64);
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct rlimit lim;
    int err;
    int i;

    pthread_t tid;

    if(getrlimit(RLIMIT_NPROC, &lim) < 0)
        perror("getrlimit error"), exit(1);

    i = 1;
    while(pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thr_crt, NULL) == 0)
        i++;

    printf("soft limit: %d\n", lim.rlim_cur);
    printf("hard limit: %d\n", lim.rlim_max);
    printf("threads %d\n", i-1);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

> soft limit: 7455
>    hard limit: 7455
>    threads 7185

It should not create 7455 threads?

Comment: Just a note: isn't `rlim_t` type unsigned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum thread number RLIMIT_NPROC is (IIRC) per "real" user id and not per process, so it makes sense that it is somewhat lower per process either because of other already running processes with the same "real" user id or as some sort of protection against rapid resource exhaustion.

Answer (score 1):

Check `/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max`, as it might be lower than the allowed processes.